Difference between DISCARD and INV command in GIC ( Generic Interrupt controller )
GIC ARM SPEC 
In the highlighted text it says
For Discard
It also ensures that any caching in the Redistributors
associated with a specific EventID is consistent with the
configuration held in memory.
For INV
Specifies that the ITS must ensure that any caching in the
Redistributors associated with the specified EventID is consistent
with the LPI Configuration tables held in memory.
Are these both statements similar? Is Discard a superset ( because it also invalidate ITT table )  of INV command? if so will Driver not issue Discard and INV together?
i looked at the  Driver code for GIC, i see that in Vlpi_unmap function it does give DICARD and INV command, seems redundant  if DISCARD does everything what INV does
